# How to show multiple results for HealthChecks in ASP.NET Core HealthChecksUI

Tags: asp.net-core

I configured my HealthChecksUI in Startup.cs as it suggested in doc.
And I added this to appsettings.json:

```
"HealthChecks": [
      {
        "Name": "Test-Api-Basic",
        "Uri": "https://localhost:44300/health/live"
      },
      {
        "Name": "API-1",
        "Uri": "https://one_more_API/dev/health/live"
      },
      {
        "Name": "API-2",
        "Uri": "https://Another_API/health/live"
      }
    ]
```

I was expecting to see in UI multiple entries but see only top one which is in this current project.
I feel that I am doing something wrong but cannot figure out. Need your help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Xabaril](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) package and add the multiple endpoint like this

```html
services.AddHealthChecksUI(setupSettings: setup =>
{
    setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Test-Api-Basic", "https://localhost:44300/health/live");
    setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("API-1", "https://one_more_API/dev/health/live");
    setup.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("API-2", "https://Another_API/health/live");
    
}).AddInMemoryStorage();
```